# Replace nested double quotes

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to replace nested double quotes with double apostrophe in json document.

I tried following code, but my regex pattern does not select correct group which needs to be changed.

```
# fixing double quote
try:
    result = re.search('claimReviewed": "(.*)",',page,re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)
    if result is not None:
        double_quoted = result.group(1)
        print(double_quoted)
        double_quoted_fixed = double_quoted.replace('"', '\'\'')
        page = page.replace(double_quoted, double_quoted_fixed)
except AttributeError as e:
    print(e)
return page
```

My test string is:

```
    "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/sonnoktasayfasi/photos/a.673944945978789/2319632444743356/?type=3&theater"
    },
    "datePublished": "02/05/2019"
  },
  "claimReviewed": "İDDİA: Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı ''Çocuklara Zekâ Geliştirici Oyuncaklar Vermeyin" şeklinde bir açıklama yaptı.&nbsp;"
```

My code snippet returns following as only changed first double quote:

```
    "sameAs": "https://www.facebook.com/sonnoktasayfasi/photos/a.673944945978789/2319632444743356/?type=3&theater"
    },
    "datePublished": "02/05/2019"
  },
  "claimReviewed": "İDDİA: Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı ''Çocuklara Zekâ Geliştirici Oyuncaklar Vermeyin" şeklinde bir açıklama yaptı.&nbsp;"
```

and desired behaviour is:
First regex pattern should group

```
İDDİA: Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı "Çocuklara Zekâ Geliştirici Oyuncaklar Vermeyin" şeklinde bir açıklama yaptı.&nbsp;
```

and then replacing it with double apostrophes, desired output should be as follows:

```
"claimReviewed": "İDDİA: Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı ''Çocuklara Zekâ Geliştirici Oyuncaklar Vermeyin'' şeklinde bir açıklama yaptı.&nbsp;",
```

Comment: If your strings always follow this format, try `s = re.sub(r'("[^"]+":\s+")(.*)"', lambda x: '{}{}"'.format(x.group(1), x.group(2).replace('"', "''")), s)`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Is it same as the code snippet i wrote? It only changed the first nested quote as my code.

Comment: [It replaces all occurrences](https://ideone.com/IzSfmO), have you tried *my* code?

Comment: I tried the code, and it only changed first double quote. Actually claimReviewed is part of html document. I updated the input.

Comment: Again, [my code replaces](https://ideone.com/pzjjEq) all `"` inside `"..."` after `"...":`.

Comment: I am so sorry for writing again, yes it is working. But original input is https://gist.github.com/isspek/6b687e69bbfbb1f5519de5c13e92e4da, and it does not replace inside double quotes. I couldn't paste all input on the question.

Comment: Try `s = re.sub(r'(:\s+")(.*(?:\n(?!\s*"[^"\n:]+":).*)*)",$', lambda x: '{}{}",'.format(x.group(1), x.group(2).replace('"', "''")), s, flags=re.M)`, see [this demo](https://rextester.com/ZGWLF45349) ([regex](https://regex101.com/r/Khd1yd/1/))

Comment: Thank you so much it works now @WiktorStribiżew I would be glad to accept your solution as answer, if you write it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(:\s+")(.*(?:\n(?!\s*"[^"\n:]+":).*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Khd1yd/1/)

**Details**

- `(:\s+")` - Group 1: `:`,  1+ whitespaces, `"`
- `(.*(?:\n(?!\s*"[^"\n:]+":).*)*)` - Group 2:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
  - `(?:\n(?!\s*"[^"\n:]+":).*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\n(?!\s*"[^"\n:]+":)` - a newline char not followed with 0+ whitespaces, `"`, 1+ chars other than newline, `"` and `:` and then a `":` substring
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/ZGWLF45349):

```
s = re.sub(r'(:\s+")(.*(?:\n(?!\s*"[^"\n:]+":).*)*)",$', lambda x: '{}{}",'.format(x.group(1), x.group(2).replace('"', "''")), s, flags=re.M)
```

Answer (score 2):

The data in your input is HTML and embedded JSON, the JSON being broken on top of that.

I'd use parsers as much as possible to approach this. For the HTML, we can use `lxml`, which makes it easy get to the text content of the interesting element (`<script type="application/ld+json">`) using XPath.

When we have the element text, we can use `json.loads()`. This works for the first such element on your sample page, but it fails for the second element with the `"Expecting ',' delimiter"` error.

The offending section is:

```
"claimReviewed": "İDDİA: Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı "Çocuklara Zekâ Geliştirici Oyuncaklar Vermeyin" şeklinde bir açıklama yaptı.

&nbsp;",
```

which would be correct as:

```
"claimReviewed": "İDDİA: Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı \"Çocuklara Zekâ Geliştirici Oyuncaklar Vermeyin\" şeklinde bir açıklama yaptı.\n\n&nbsp;",
```

So there are two things to fix:

- missing backslashes before double quotes
- the literal newlines must be replaced by `\n`

After that the JSON should parse.

We can use the exception information from the JSON parser to make the appropriate repairs in the JSON, repeatedly trying to parse it until it either succeeds, or runs into a kind of error that it does not yet know how to fix.

```
# json_utils.py
import json

class JsonRepairError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, e, text):
        message = "Don't know how to fix '%s', position %s (-->%s<--)" % (e.msg, e.pos, text[e.pos-5:e.pos+5])
        super().__init__(message)
        self.text = text

def json_repair(text):
    while True:
        try:
            return json.loads(text)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
            if e.msg == "Expecting ',' delimiter":
                if text[e.pos-1] == '"':
                    text = text[:e.pos-1] + '\\' + text[e.pos-1:]
                    continue
                elif text[e.pos-2] == '"':
                    text = text[:e.pos-2] + '\\' + text[e.pos-2:]
                    continue
            elif e.msg == "Invalid control character at":
                if text[e.pos] == '\n':
                    text = text[:e.pos] + '\\n' + text[e.pos+1:]
                    continue

            raise JsonRepairError(e, text) from None
```

which we can use like this:

```
import requests
from html import unescape
from lxml import html
from json_utils import json_repair

response = requests.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/isspek/6b687e69bbfbb1f5519de5c13e92e4da/raw")
tree = html.fromstring(response.content)

elem = tree.findall('.//script[@type="application/ld+json"]')[-1]
text = unescape(elem.text)  # this gets rid of the stray &nbsp; in the data

data = json_repair(text)
print(data["claimReviewed"])
```

This prints the correct output:

```
İDDİA: Diyanet İşleri Başkanlığı "Çocuklara Zekâ Geliştirici Oyuncaklar Vermeyin" 
şeklinde bir açıklama yaptı.
```

The advantage is that it's easy to adapt this approach to any previously unhandled type of error - just add a couple of `if`/`elif` checks and make the apporopriate repair. This is much harder to do with regex. It's also much more resilient to format changes in the HTML and overall easier to maintain.